# How can I save set of altered images in new folder in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have folder that consists of 10 images.

I am trying to apply a gaussian filter to each of them. I read images from a folder named `dd` and then I want to save the altered images in `newfolder`. However, when I look at the image it is empty.

How can I do this in correct way , read 10 images , filter them , save altered 10 images in new folder.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
for img = 1:10
    a = imread(['\dd\',int2str(img),'.pgm']);

    G = fspecial('gaussian',[3 3],2);
    Ig = imfilter(a,G,'same');

    imshow(Ig);
    imwrite( Ig, 'Ig.pgm '); % does not work !!
    save ([ path,'\newfolder\', 'new.pgm'],'Ig');% it save empty image !!!
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save` is not for saving images. Instead, you will want to use `imwrite` for that. You will also want to provide the full path to `imwrite` and here we use `mat2gray` just to ensure that your data covers the entire dynamic range of the image type. You'll also want to be sure that each output image has a unique name so that they don't overwrite one another.

```
output_filename = fullfile(path, 'newfolder', sprintf('%d_new.pgm', img));
imwrite(mat2gray(Ig), output_filename, 'pgm');
```

As a side note, you'll want to use `fullfile` to reliably construct your folder paths across computers and operating systems.

Comment: Suever  thank you , it works now ... i spent two days to slove it